# Find and delete file but not specific path

Tags: linux, bash, shell, automation, find

I am writing a script to cleanup user dir on "/srv". At present every user keeps some temp files on "/srv/$USER".

Following is my script :

```
for x in $(cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd); do 
   if [ -d "/srv/${x}" ]; then
   echo "/srv/${x}"
   find /srv/${x} -mindepth 1 -type f -not -amin -10080 -exec rm {} \;
   fi
done
```

So I tried this script replacing rm with ls

```
/srv/abc
/srv/abc/2015-04-20-11-multi-interval.json
/srv/abc/2015-04-20-10-mimic.json
/srv/xyz
/srv/xyz/magnetic_hadoop/fabfile.py
```

here i want to exclude */srv/abc* which is parent dir and delete only files, So I added *-mindepth 1*, but still I didn't get what I want.

Then I added *-not -path /srv/${x}* but no difference.

Anyone know what am I missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to exclude `/srv/xyz` as well?

Comment: yes, basically want to exclude parent dir

Comment: But those are already being excluded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the '-type f' means that you will get only files. and your output shows that: after the folder name which comes from the echo command, only files are shown.
unless you want to leave user folders intact, you don't want the '-mindepth 1' option; it does not change the fact that '-type f'